# speech to text engines: what's your experience?

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I just tried out IBM Watson's demo for automatic speech to text transcription. I tried the record button to transcribe my voice live using Firefox as browser. Most of the time the transcription was wrong or missing words. I also read about how Ted talks are transcribed, and I learned that they do it manually by having volunteers. I'd like to hear from anyone who has experience with speech to text engines about their experience with the current state of the technology. It doesn't seem to be good enough to transcribe text on the fly, nor is it good enough to transcribe text without serious manual intervention.

Link to IBM Watson speech to text demo

https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=39462201527514462925457&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1447335949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! We just fixed the bug that the Speech-To-Text demo had in Firefox (it always worked fine on Chrome). Audio capture was bad after the first run, and corrupted audio was being fed into IBM Watson Speech-To-Text service, causing really bad recognition accuracy.

Please give it a try: https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Comment: I just tried it on Firefox from my Sony experia phone. I said "Jingle Bells" a few times and this is what I got: Jingle. I. Jingle bell. Go dell. Jim was. Rebels. Nobel. You go to bed. Jingle. Just. Those. We'll both. Jingle bells. Jingle bells. Jingle bells. Jingle bell. Good. Bells. Jingle. Jim. Gilbert. Rebels. Jingle. Jingle.

Comment: Hello shadi, you wont get good accuracy trying the demo application from a mobile browser. The STT demo uses the webaudio api, which seems to produce corrupted audio on the mobile version of both Chrome and Firefox. This results in very poor accuracy. 

The good news is that we have released open source SDKs to build native applications in both iOS and Android. Please take a look at them, they come with a sample application, the accuracy is excellent:

Android: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk

iOS: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-ios-sdk